# I have unallocated space in my C drive. I want to make it primary partition but it is being created as logical partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have unallocated space in my C drive. I want to make it primary partition but it is being created as logical partition. How can I make it primary partition.

I have unallocated space in my C drive. I want to make it primary partition but it is being created as logical partition. How can I make it primary partition